# Ниже код. Он принимает двузначное положительное число и выводит разницу между большим и меньшим цифрами числа. Прошу помочь сделать код короче

Tags: javascript

```
    const a = +prompt('enter a positive two-digit integer');
        if (a < 100 && a > 10) {
          const b = String(a).split('').map(i=>Number(i));
          if(+b[0]>+b[1]){
            console.log(+(b[0]-b[1]));
          }else if (+b[0]<+b[1]){
            console.log(+(b[1]-b[0]));
          }else(
            console.log('the numbers are equal')
          );
          
        } else(
          console.log('enter a positive two-digit integer'));
```

Comment: Уберите все `+`-ы.

Comment: Без них работает не корректно.  Проверяйте советы пержде пожалуйста. Код может быть короче не благодаря минусам

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Будем использовать строковое представление пользовательского ввода. По условиям задачи, длина строки равна 2, строка может быть преобразована в положительное целое число.

```js
const number = prompt("Enter a positive two-digit integer");
if (!(c=Number(number)) || c%1 || c<0 || number.length != 2) console.log("Введите положительное двузначное число");
else console.log((r=Math.abs((n = number.split(""))[0]-n[1]))==0?"Числа равны":r);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Очевидно лучше

Comment: @АлександрИванов Очевидно худше.

Comment: Дружище. Судя по ответам твоим репутация возможно тебе не соответствует. Был задан вопрос на который нужен ответ. Если есть код лучше пиши. Нет ответа не трать время.

Comment: Если ввести `.5`, результат будет неожиданным.

Comment: @Yaant. Вы правы. Что то пошло не так. Не могли бы указать на место ошибки?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что условие "двузначное положительное число" не эквивалентно условию "строка не содержит знаков "-", её длина равна 2, строка может быть преобразована в число."